# Export d3 chart and send it through mail as an interactive graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using d3 charts to render graphs. 
Now in my application i have the option of "Email." on click of which the graph should be exported to the 'Compose email' screen. And this graph in the email should have the same interactive functionalities as in the browser like hover, onclick of graph etc. 
Is this possible? Please suggest ways i can do this. I need to this on the client side using javascript, jquery etc.

Thanks

Comment: use javascript to convert the array of data points which d3 uses, into a string suitable for use in a mailto: link

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the graph itself is easy, as its svg. So for that you can just write the svg to a text file and name it accordingly. To preserve the animations is a bit tricky. Maybe you could compose an HTML message. However, I'd assume most email clients to not execute the JavaScript. Also, where do you get the raw data from? This is also something that you have to consider. If you retrieve the data from an internal source at the client, you will have to somehow embed it and change your d3 import accordingly.
Hope that helps at least a bit.

Cheers
Hendrik

Comment: Ill be making an ajax call to hit the url and retrieve the data from the backend. it will in the form of a json. Does d3 have an api to export the chart with the animations?